# Eclipse Xdebug initiated from firefox when server and local copy are the same

Tags: eclipse, firefox, xdebug

I apologize in advance if this question has already been asked. I've been searching for hours and haven't found the correct solution.

Situation:
Eclipse Helios PDT with Xdebug v2.1.0, and firefox with easy Xdebug plugin. Workspace source files are the same as the deployed server source files.

I can launch debug sessions manually from eclipse without a problem. However when I initiate the session from firefox (via a the XDebug plugin) directly they always open a new editor with the absolute path to the file. When the debugging this way (via firefox initiated absolute path) I cannot set or remove breakpoints on the fly, change variables, open declarations, etc.

If I try debugging from firefox where the server path is not the same as the local/workspace, I get a path mapping pop-up. From the pop-up I am able to select the file in the project I want no problem and set/remove breakpoints. If the server file is the same as the local file there is no pop-up.

I'm sure I am missing something obvious..

Comment: Did you edit this post without signing in? If so, your note will have gone in as an edit in need of review and may not be accepted.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Thanks I have logged in now.